Error Enabling Defender for XDR Connector in Microsoft Sentinel: "AADSTS50131: Device is not in required device state"
I am trying to enable the Defender for XDR connector in Microsoft Sentinel, but it consistently throws the following error:
  {
      "sessionId": "",
      "errors": [
        {
          "errorMessage": "interaction_required: AADSTS50131: Device is not in required device state: known. Or, the request was blocked due to suspicious activity, access policy, or security policy decisions. Trace ID: XX Correlation ID: XX Timestamp: 2024-07-27 13:40:27Z",
          "clientId": "bda0771f-b6df-474a-b348-26a308db88aa",
          "scopes": [
            "https://securitycenter.microsoft.com/mtp/.default"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }

From my research, it appears that the error is related to the device compliance state, suggesting that only a compliant device can set up the connector. However, I do not understand why there is a need for a compliant device to set up the connector in the first place.
My Questions:

Why does enabling the Defender for XDR connector require a compliant device?
Is there a way to disable this compliance requirement, or is there a workaround for this issue?
What steps can I take to troubleshoot and resolve this error given that my current device cannot be added as compliant?

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
